# Unable to access List in JSTL

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I use the following code to a List of "Item" objects.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/garageHome", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView displayFilteredItems(@ModelAttribute("command") GarageHomeViewModel model){
    //PERFORM SEARCH AND RETURN
    logger.info("Search submitted: " + model.getSearchFilters().getAllTypes());
    List<Item> list = itemService.findItems(model.getSearchFilters());

    logger.info("Num results: " + list.size());

    model.setItems(list);

    return new ModelAndView("/garageHome", "command", model);
}
```

And the following code to iterate through it in JSTL...

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="status">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${status.count % 4 == 0 && status.count >= 4}">
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                            </c:when>
                        </c:choose>
                        <th>
                            <div>
                                <a href="<c:url value="/productDetails.do?id=${item.getID()}" />"><img class="hotDealImages" src="${item.getImageLink()}" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hotDealsText">"${item.getDescr()}"</div>
                            <div class="hotDealsText">Bid</div>
                            <div class="hotDealsText">Location</div>
                        </th>
                    </c:forEach>
```

But nothing gets printed.

I tried the following code to print out the number of elements in the list and that prints 0.

```
<th>Hot Deals ${fn:length($items)}</th>
```

But, the line `logger.info("Num results: " + list.size());`  prints "2" in the console.

Why am I getting the number of elements in the list as 0 in JSTL ? and What could be wrong with my forEach loop ?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated. I am very new to Spring MVC 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSP you shouldn't call `${item.getDescr()}` but `${item.descr}`. This will call the `getDescr()` method on the item's class.

Comment: That, plus the bean name "command" has to be explicitly mentioned in the forEach loop.

i.e. items = "${command.items}"